# How to see the log or results from PIP

Tags: python, pip

Using python PIP (pypi) in Windows 7, how can I keep the pop up window open to see the results of the install (especially if there was an issue)? Or Is there a log that I can review?

Ex:
pip install selenium2Library

Answer (score 1):

I figured an easy work around.. use this:

```
\Python27\python.exe \Python27\Scripts\pip-2.7-script.py install eyed3
```

This runs in the current cmd window, instead of a new one that auto closes when done.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best solution, because I'm still looking for a proper answer, but what is currently working for me is instead of running `pip` from the `command prompt` I'm using `cygwin` instead. Exactly the same commands to use it: `pip install module` except that `cygwin` seems to catch the output of the program.

Find cygwin here: http://cygwin.com/install.html

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for some of my coworkers, but not me.

We had downloaded a pip binary.  We fixed it by uninstalling pip, running [ez_setup](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py), then running easy_install pip.